# Autogenerate Columns from data in grid control

Tags: c#, devexpress

I set the datasource for a WPF `dxg:GridControl` to that of a hard coded list.

```
        gridControl1.ItemsSource = new List<Entity> { new Entity() { Name = "1" }, new Entity() { Name = "2" }, new Entity() { Name = "3" } };
```

I have to specify each column in the XAML:

```
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Name" Name="gridColumn1" />
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Column2" Name="gridColumn2" />
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
```

How can I get the columns to autogenerate instead of specifying XAML?

I tried removing the columns.  That displayed nothing.  The data actually comes from a WCF service at runtime, so the "Populate Columns" button in design mode is probably not going to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a stab in the dark, but other grids in WPF usually have something like this...

```
<dxg:GridControl AutoPopulateColumns ="True">
```

(edit to get actual property name)

Comment: Yeah all those 3rd party controls like to change the names of things slightly, did that fix the problem?

Comment: Yes.  Marking as answer after timer runs out.